# Less time consuming options searching content of a file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have around 50.000 text files sorted into a folder per day, for example:

```
/rootdir/20130831/ (containing 50000 files)
/rootdir/20130907/ (containing 50000 files)
/rootdir/20130908/ (containing 50000 files)
/rootdir/20130909/ (containing 50000 files)
```

Now I made a search script that combines find and grep together. The find command is build up dynamically based on the users input. So if the user only knows the year he wants to search. The search will be done over all 2013 folders.

Then the user also inputs some search data. This can be up to 3 search strings, resulting into a search like:

```
find /rootdir/2013*/ -type f | xargs grep -l searchstring1 | xargs grep -l searchstring2 | xargs grep -l searchstring3
```

This can be ofcourse time consuming. I was wondering if I could get the time per search down? Are there any less time consuming ways?

*** EDIT *** Forgot to mention that the filenames can also not be used to shorten down the result of the find command.

Comment: @matcheek: What do you mean with index the content?

Comment: I meant inverted index for example - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index  though never tried that in bash.

Comment: Oh wait! Someone has already done inverted indices in bash http://staff.science.uva.nl/~marx/teaching/zoekmachines/LectureNotes/Practica/MakeInvertedIndex/MakeInvertedIndex.html Judging by the sheer look it must have been in the early ages of the internet but looks complete.
if you are keen on switching to Python - NLTK http://nltk.org/

Comment: If efficient searching is required, you should store the information in a database instead of a set of plain text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one process with one interpreter language should be faster. And here's one for Ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'find'

dir = ARGV.shift
year = ARGV.shift
patterns = ARGV.map{|a| Regexp.new(Regexp.quote(a)).freeze}

Dir.glob("#{dir}/#{year}**").each do |d|
  Find.find(d).drop(1).select{|f| File.file?(f)}.each do |f|
    text = File.read(f)
    match = true
    patterns.each do |p|
      unless p =~ text
        match = false
        break
      end
    end
    puts f if match
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
ruby script.rb /rootdir 2013 searchstring1 searchstring2 searchstring3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to make sure that you're searching for the most limiting string first.

If "foo" is in 10000 files and "bar" is in 100 files, then it will be slower to

```
# Find 10000 matching files, then search for bar in them.
find .... | xargs grep -l foo | xargs grep -l bar
```

instead of

```
# Find 100 matching files, then search for foo in them.
find .... | xargs grep -l bar | xargs grep -l foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really an overlong comment, but: one thing I've found is directories that slowly accumulate thousands of files tend to have contents, and *equally* importantly inodes, scattered all over the disk.  `dpkg/info` was the one that got me to investigate after a year or so's accumulation, and a quick

```
cd current
find -print0 | sort -z | cpio -pdv0 ../new
mv ../current ../new
mv ../new ../current
```

tends assign inode numbers and allocate contents sequentially.  `ls -il` to check, if you see a mishmash of inode numbers it might be worth doing this.  Tens of thousands of seeks for the inodes is nothing to sneeze at.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /rootdir/2013*/ -type f | xargs grep -l searchstring1 | xargs grep -l searchstring2 | xargs grep -l searchstring3
```

might be mildly faster if you instead did:

```
egrep -Rl 'searchstring1|searchstring2|searchstring3' /rootdir/2013*
```

Also, it's worth noting that

> I have around 50.000 text files sorted into a folder

...may not be an optimal use case for your filesystem.  Some of them do many orders of magnitude better than others for many-files, or many-files-per-directory.  Consider benchmarking different ones.